# Как сделать что бы полоса индикаторов при ресайзе сохраняла своё положение на изображении без смены html?

Tags: css

Как сделать такое, пример представлен

```css
.b-about__carousel-inner {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about__indicator-list {
  margin-top: -54px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  margin-top: -74px;
  position: absolute;
}
.b-about__indicator-list li {
  width: 17px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.b-about__indicator-item.active {
  width: 17px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #ed454b;
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.b-about__container-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about__image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.b-about__information {
  padding: 91px 15px 0 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div role="listbox" class="b-about__carousel-inner carousel-inner">
  <div class="active b-about__item item">
    <div class="b-about__container-image">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTD60q-ZK6Jnex3EvBk8tjS205SgzGkqzCQ0qDhgy-D84lrtTax151OVPs" alt="" title="" class="b-about__image">
    </div>
    <div class="b-about__information">
      <h2 class="b-title b-title--about">Двигатель</h2>
      <div class="b-about__text-about">
        <p>Надежный, прочный и&nbsp;экономичный 4-цилиндровый двигатель</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Controls-->

  <ol class="b-about__indicator-list carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="0" class="active b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="1" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="2" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="3" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="4" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно уточнить по поводу что значит "сохраняла своё положение"? Была по центру или имела какую-то фиксированную позицию? Я так понимаю речь идёт о `<ol class="b-about__indicator-list carousel-indicators">`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov сохранял позицию относительно низа картинки

Comment: Хорошо, а зачем `margin-top: -74px;`? к чему именно `74px`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov  .b-about__carousel-inner я беру половину высоты и отрицательным margin правлю по макету. Но при ресайзе, уже меняют свое положение.

Comment: Можно было бы просто `bottom` задать в процентах по макету и всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо позиция относительно низа картинки, так и задайте её относительно низа то есть `bottom`. При этом, в данном случае не нужно указывать `margin` для абсолютно позиционируемых элементов, хотя бывают случаи, когда это уместно. Если контейнер имеет фиксированный размер, то укажите единицы измерения в пикселях, если контейнер резиновый, то в процентах.

И общий совет: поменьше используйте магических чисел вроде `74px`.

Comment: Бинго, просто пиксели указать я не догадался! Спасибо!

Comment: так у него внизу картинки внутри `b-about__item` еще есть блок `b-about__information`, высота которого неизвестна, как и высота картинки, они разные при ресайзе, как можно это сделать при помощи только `bottom` и только css, я слабо понимаю, может я туплю, объясните

Comment: @drtvader так вы же мне написали, что высота `b-about__information` тоже меняется при ресайзе, как вы тогда указали отступ в пикселях?

Comment: @drtvader вы сейчас указали `bottom`, например 300px, а при ресайзе у вас `b-about__information` станет высотой 400px и что тогда, где окажется ваша навигация?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич самое интересное, что работает.

Comment: @drtvader так а что вы сейчас указали? просто `bottom` в пикселях и всё?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич да, просто bottom в пикселях.

Comment: @drtvader ну тогда не удивляйтесь когда ваша навигация съедет, если увеличится количество текста в `b-about__information` или изменится соотношение сторон картинки

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич контент фиксированный в этом проекте)

Answer (score 0):

Если без изменения html, то только javascript-ом задавать `top` для ваших индикаторов равный высоте изображения и `margin-top` отрицательный на нужный отступ снизу

```js
var imgHeight = $('.b-about__container-image').height()
$('.b-about__indicator-list').css('top', imgHeight);

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  imgHeight = $('.b-about__container-image').height()
  $('.b-about__indicator-list').css('top', imgHeight);
});
```

```css
.b-about__carousel-inner {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about__indicator-list {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.b-about__indicator-list li {
  width: 17px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.b-about__indicator-item.active {
  width: 17px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #ed454b;
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.b-about__container-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.b-about__image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.b-about__information {
  padding: 91px 15px 0 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="listbox" class="b-about__carousel-inner carousel-inner">
  <div class="active b-about__item item">
    <div class="b-about__container-image">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTD60q-ZK6Jnex3EvBk8tjS205SgzGkqzCQ0qDhgy-D84lrtTax151OVPs" alt="" title="" class="b-about__image">
    </div>
    <div class="b-about__information">
      <h2 class="b-title b-title--about">Двигатель</h2>
      <div class="b-about__text-about">
        <p>Надежный, прочный и&nbsp;экономичный 4-цилиндровый двигатель</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Controls-->

  <ol class="b-about__indicator-list carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="0" class="active b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="1" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="2" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="3" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
    <li data-target="#about" data-slide-to="4" class="b-about__indicator-item"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

А так, вообще нужно перенести индикаторы в `b-about__container-image` и спокойно указывать ему нужный `bottom`

Comment: Переносить невозможно, это карусель, в каждый элемент карусели тоже не вариант.

Comment: @drtvader Ну тогда только js, как я написал, `b-about__information` же тоже не фиксированной высоты и при ресайзе может изменятся?

Comment: да, может меняться.